# How to call widget class in different module in PYQT with multiple Ui file structure

Tags: python, pyqt

The issue comes from the multi-module Pyqt structure.

To get you to speed, all of my files with the issue are readily available [in github repo here.](https://github.com/Kokokoko666/unavailable_widget)

I downloaded the code from the Stackoverflow inquiry about the side bar in PYQT when using [multiple UI file structure.](https://stackoverflow.com)

[@Eyllanesc, kudos to his help with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) answered the question and provided an example [here.](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/53899209)

The issue is, when calling Pyqt5 objects (such as lineEdit) via Widget class it throws various errors.
I am trying (for the sake of this example) fill one lineEdit in module `customerpage.py`  with the text from other lineEdit in module `loginpage.py`.

call in loginpage.py (works)

```
    def test(self):
        try:
            return CustomerWidget.test_func(self.lineEdit_server.text())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

receiving in customerpage.py (error)

```
    def test_func(name):
        print(name)
        CustomerWidget.parent().lineEdit_cust_name.setText(name)
```

The errors that I get when referencing CustomerWidget in the module `customerpage` are following.

For  reference as `CustomerWidget` it is error `type object 'CustomerWidget' has no attribute 'lineEdit_cust_name`.
For reference as `CustomerWidget()` it is error `wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted`.
For reference as `CustomerWidget().parent().` it is error `NoneType' object has no attribute 'lineEdit_cust_name'`.
For reference as `CustomerWidget.parent().` it is error `parent(self): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QObject'`.

How to refer to the widget class in other module with the PYQT Ui structure that it gets recognised?

#### Structure

```
├── main.py
├── pages
│   ├── loginpage.py
│   └── customer.py
└── ui
    ├── main.ui
    ├── login.ui
    └── customer.ui
```

#### main.py

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtGui, uic, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView
from functools import partial

import os.path
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Form, Base = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(current_dir, "ui/main.ui"))

class MainWidget(Base, Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
  
        buttons = (self.loginbutton,self.customerbutton)
        for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex, i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Breeze")      
    w = MainWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### loginpage.py

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtGui, uic
import ctypes

import os.path
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))

from .customerpage import CustomerWidget

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Form, Base = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(current_dir, "../ui/login.ui"))

class LoginWidget(Base, Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_test.clicked.connect(self.test)
        self.lineEdit_server.setText("localhost")

        
    def test(self):
        try:
            return CustomerWidget.test_func(self.lineEdit_server.text())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LoginWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### customerpage.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlQuery


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QMessageBox
)
import os
import os.path
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Form, Base = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(current_dir, "../ui/customer.ui"))


class CustomerWidget(Base, Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit_cust_name.setText("")

    def test_func(name):
        print(name)
        CustomerWidget.parent().lineEdit_cust_name.setText(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CustomerWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there is an issue with accessing the objects, as they are not recognized as class variables.
This might not be a proper way how to do it in PYQT but it certainly works for this example. It can be done by declaring them within `__init__` of thewidget class.

`CustomerWidget.lineEdit_cust_name = self.lineEdit_cust_name`